# Question mark after function parameter in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to dart and flutter, when i am using Stream, i found this function

```
StreamSubscription<T> listen(void onData(T event)?,
  {Function? onError, void onDone()?, bool? cancelOnError});
```

Can someone tell me what does the '?' mean here?

Comment: It adds null safety to the function parameters? That question mark means the parameter can be the specified type or null but nothing else. Dart no longer support null as subtype of known types so is the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Dart 2.12, the language supports null safety. Here, `?` explicitly states that a variable/parameter may be null.

Learn more [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety) and watch [this](https://youtu.be/iYhOU9AuaFs) video

Comment: Dart has a war against `null`... ‍♀️ How many times have we read "xxx was called on null" in our crash logs!  Well, no more of that, I guess... Instead, we just have to fill our code with question marks and exclamation marks..... 